# How do I reference Flash IDE instances from within Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder

Say I have a Movie Clip "Gameboard" which consists of several other Movie Clips like "Counter" and "MessageBox". 
Each of these sub clips in turn have instances like TextFields ("myScore") or graphic symbols.

Each of these classes is complex in that they respond to events/signals so I need to reference them

My current approach has been to set export settings on all clips (mypackagename.Counter for eg.) which has a mypackagename.Counter.as in FlashBuilder. Then once the parent (Gameboard) has been added to the stage, I recurse through all the children and access by index (i know..very bad).. something like this (don't have this snippet handy but only illustrates the bad code I want to remove)

```
 function findChild(doc:DisplayObjectContainer):void
 {

       //loop through doc.children
       //get current child . ToString check if its [ object Counter ] etc
       // if a match is found set a variable locally to reference it
 }
```

Considering that child movie clips may exist only on different frames, how can I safely access an instance of "myCounter" by name or type or even one of it's children ("myTextField").

I have a fairly convoluted workflow - in that I import an illustrator file which contains a single Gameboard asset which contains the design for the Counter and other child MC's. JSFL is used to convert Piece Shapes to Movie Clips then multi-swapped to a single Piece. When I change the automatically declare stage instances setting I get multiple errors so hopefully there is a solution that avoids this setting.

Would it be possible to convert a gameboard to a component in Flash IDE and create a property within the IDE that refers to "myCounter" for example?

Thanks for reading!!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand you correctly, but you can access the child-movieclips or textfields through it's name. In that case, you could create 1 class for the GameBoard and create some getters for the children

- MovieClip GameBoard with a class GameBoard added to it.
- MovieClip myCounter, child of GameBoard MovieClip, and with **name** myCounter
- TextField myTf, child of myCounter, with **name** myTf

  ```
  package {
  public class GameBoard extends MovieClip {
    private function get _myCounter():MovieClip { return this["myCounter"]; }
    private function get _myTf():TextField { return _myCounter["myTf"]; }
  }
  }
  ```

You can also just just this["myCounter"] and this["myCounter"]["myTf"] in you code, but i prefer creating getters for it.